# Calling a Drawable-Resource by a String

Tags: java, android, string, resources

So, let me explain the default situation at first: A user can choose a picture - and this picture is saved by a string (e.g. "picture1") in a Properties-file. Now I wan't to display the picture by loading the String off the Properties-file and getting the Image out of my Drawables-Resources by R.drawable.MYPICTURE.

this is what I worked out:

```
    String iconsString[] = {"default", "icon"};
    int iconsResource[] = {R.drawable.default, R.drawable.icon};

    int iconResourcePosition;
    int iconsStringLength = iconsString.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < iconsStringLength; i++) {
        if (iconsString[i] == mProperties.getProperty("icon")) {
            iconResourcePosition = i;
        } else {
            iconResourcePosition = 0;
        }
    }
    btn_profileIcon.setBackgroundDrawable(iconsResource[iconResourcePosition]);
```

But it doesn't work, since the ".setBackgroundDrawable" does not accept int-values. Well, and that's where I'm stuck. I could make the "iconsResource[]" beeing "Drawable" instead of "int", but that would cause an other problem :|

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

mmmm don't you want to do something like this:

```
btn_profileIcon.setBackgroundResource(iconsResource[iconResourcePosition]);
```

Comment: Sounds interesting but that method is implemented by View and set the background, not the contained image (from ImageView). Worth a try.

Comment: @JustBasti you're welcome :) I would have made the same mistake in another time ^^

@Renaud, well seems you're right, I think the main difference is that the background will resize the view, and not the contained image, not the same use I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Use BitmapFactory.decodeResource(…) to store a reusable Bitmap and then use setImageBitmap(…) on your ImageView (or derived).